# Upload image to the server using multipartentity and json in android

Tags: android, json

I have read lots of post to achieve the task like to upload image along with parameters using multipartentity and josn in android, but my problem is when i was trying to upload image and parameter without converting string to `JSONobject` then image has uploaded without an error but when i was trying to add response string to jsonobject then error occur in the logcat like ):

```
error: Value`<form of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject.
```

Any one please help to resolve this issue? I want to send an image and `JsonObjec`t to an PHP Server with `MultipartEntity`. I am working on an app that allows the user upload an image by using H`ttpPost` method. I use `MultipartEntity` and therefore I added the libraries apache-mime4j-0.6.1.jar, httpclient-4.3.1.jar, httpcore-4.3.1.jar and httpmime-4.2.1.jar into my app.

Here is my Code:

```
    public JSONObject doFileUpload(String _fname, String _lname, String _email,
                String _password, String _country, String _countrycode,
                String _phone) {

            File file1 = new File(selectedPath);
            String urlString = "http://capstonehostingservices.com/fetch_new/app/index.php/fetch/register";
            try {
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost(urlString);
                FileBody bin1 = new FileBody(file1);
                MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
                reqEntity.addPart("photo", bin1);
                reqEntity.addPart("first_name", new StringBody(_fname));
                reqEntity.addPart("last_name", new StringBody(_lname));
                reqEntity.addPart("email", new StringBody(_email));
                reqEntity.addPart("password", new StringBody(_password));
                reqEntity.addPart("country", new StringBody(_country));
                reqEntity.addPart("country_code", new StringBody(_countrycode));
                reqEntity.addPart("phone", new StringBody(_phone));

                post.setEntity(reqEntity);
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                resEntity = response.getEntity();
                 String response_str = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);



                    json = new JSONObject(response_str);


            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
            }
            return json;
        }
```

In above code i was trying to convert response string to jsonobject, how to i achieve this?
I used selectedpath parameter as to get image path from gallary, I want to send an image and a `JsonObject` to an PHP Server with `MultipartEntity`. I am working on an app that allows the user upload an image by using `HttpPost` method. I use `MultipartEntity` and therefore I added the libraries apache-mime4j-0.6.1.jar, httpclient-4.3.1.jar, httpcore-4.3.1.jar and httpmime-4.2.1.jar into my app.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the best answer but it is a very good example to get started.

Use the following function to send file to server:

```
public static void postFile(String fileName) throws Exception {//fileName is path+filename of picture
        String url_upload_image = "http://url-to-api/upload_photo.php";
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url_upload_image);
        MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder
                .create();
        multipartEntity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        multipartEntity.addPart("file", new FileBody(new File(fileName)));
        post.addHeader("id", id);//id is anything as you may need
        post.setEntity(multipartEntity.build());
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        entity.consumeContent();
        client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
```

PHP file that is at `http://url-to-api/upload_photo.php`

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['id'];

    $file_path = "images/";

    $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']);

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
        echo "success";
        echo $name;
    } else{
        echo "fail";
    }
 ?>
```

**And make sure that your directory or folder in server is Executable, Writable and Readable.** I had this as the major problem. This is **called 777 permission**.. Believe me, this is as important as other things to consider.